# htaccess mod_rewrite on localhost

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect all urls like localhost/test/v1/rates to api.php in /test/v1/ folder and calls to localhost/test/v2/rates to api.php in /test/v2/ folder (MAMP server)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ./v1/(.*)$ /test/v1/api.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

The code before just does not work. I just exhausted almost all possibilities.

Please send me in the right direction.

Comment: Remember that the first argument of `RewriteRule` is a regular expression. `./something` makes no sense as regex. Find out what exactly you are matching against. In `.htaccess` context, the folder the `.htaccess` file is in will be removed from the url you are matching against. The url will never begin with a `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /test/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^v1/(.*)/?$ /test/v1/api.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^v2/(.*)/?$ /test/v2/api.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>


</IfModule>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using `RewriteBase /test/`, you must add the directory to the rules like
`RewriteRule ^/test/index\.php$ - [L]`.

Don't use `./` as entry point.

Comment: `.htaccess` is listed. The first argument of `RewriteRule` in a `.htaccess` file is NEVER tested against an url that starts with a `/`, because the folder the `.htaccess` file is in is removed as a prefix and later re-added.